# Multi mobile OS simulator

Tags: html, simulator, mobile-os

I am trying to find Simulators for multiple mobile Operating Systems, but i am always getting Emulators instead.

What i need basically is maybe a Web Version of different mobile OS, not to run or test applications, just to navigate through their menu and settings (go at settings, change settings, setup email etc.)

The purpose for this is to guide through users on how to change their settings on their phones, without the need of the actual device or having multiple emulators.

**UPDATE**

After a lot of search around i managed to find an Android web simulator that suits my needs at **[Manymo](https://www.manymo.com/emulators)**.
It has versions : 4.2 , 4.1 , 4.0.3 , 2.3 , 2.2 , 2.1

Still in search for something similar for iOS, Windows Phone and Blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily set up such emulators with a bit of CSS and jQuery (for the animations when changing screens).
From time to time I run into such "simulators" on cell-provider companies' websites. But they are very limited to a teaching a few functions, and are accompanied by text on the side.

You might want to hire a web developer, give him 3-4 days and then you have a nice simulator for the 3 popular OSes.

Just beware that having an Android simulator may not be enough; The OS changes with the devices, as manufacturers do whatever they want with the OS and compile for their specific device.

Comment: I wanted to avoid going through this process as this will require updating the web app constantly every time there is an update from one of the OSes. So was hoping to find some software that does something similar.

Comment: Well the major version updates come out every year, and only once a few years there's actually something to change in the basic stuff. Settings app does not change a lot and you can still guide users how to setup their email etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/ then perhaps. Or do you want it for apps rather than web pages? Then I don't think it's possible.

There are packages like jQuery Mobile that is designed to generate web apps that look like native mobile apps.

Comment: I want it for the OS menu/settings. Nothing to do with apps or webpages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a free account on http://deviceanywhere.com?

Answer (score 0):

There are some 'fun' apps built for Windows Phone to emulate other phones

- [iFun](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ifun/9cdca819-9f53-e011-854c-00237de2db9e) - iPhone simulator
- [Fundroid](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/fundroid/c8e4751a-b169-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8) - Android simulator
- [B7B](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/b7b/1c5f58bc-0469-441a-b7dd-169a7bf0086b) - BlackBerry simulator

I haven't tried them out myself so I can't say how well they simulate phone settings, but is this kind of what you're looking for?